# supervisor 'can't find command ../bin/gunicorn', что делать?

Tags: linux, сервер, консоль, gunicorn, supervisord

файл djngtest в conf.d:

```
[program:djngtest]
command=home/andreyj/projects/proj1/mvenv/bin/gunicorn djngtest.wsgi -c home/andreyj/projects/proj1/djngtest/djngtest/gunicorn.conf.py

directory=home/andreyj/projects/proj1/djngtest/
user=nobody
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
```

команды в supervisor:

```
supervisor> reread
supervisor> update 
supervisor> status djngtest
```

на что получаю:

```
djngtest                         BACKOFF   can't find command 'home/andreyj/projects/proj1/mvenv/bin/gunicorn'
```

уже хз что делать помогите плиз.

Comment: Слэш перед home забыли?

Comment: [Путь может быть абсолютным или относительным. Полный или абсолютный путь — это путь, который указывает на одно и то же место в файловой системе, вне зависимости от текущего рабочего каталога или других обстоятельств. Полный путь всегда начинается с корневого каталога.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BA_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%83)

Comment: когда поставил слешь, стал выдаватьтакую ошибку
djngtest                         BACKOFF   Exited too quickly (process log may have details)

Comment: запустил, надо было user=root сделать